# Fixed - Alsa: usb sound card detected but not useable

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, manjaro

Recently I got a new usb external soundcard. When I plug in with Manjaro Linux running(my laptop gets no trouble to play on internal soundcard). The soundcard was detected as these showed in `alsamixer`: [alsamixer screenshoot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyJX4.png).

However when I want to play something, the sound is from my internal speaker but not the earphone connected to usb soundcard. So I edit `~/.asoundrc` and this is the content

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
} 
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
}
```

I rebooted but nothing changed, the sound is always playing on internal speaker. What could be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Remove your `~/.asoundrc`. If you are **not** running Pulseaudio: use `aplay -L` to get list of devices, use `aplay -D plughw:CARD=... some_file.wav` with the device listed to test if a WAV file (not MP3 etc.) plays on the USB card. With Pulseaudio: Use `pavucontrol` to select output ("sink").

Comment: Click `Set as fallback` in `pavucontrol` works for me, thank you.